How to create a submatrix from a given matrix M by eliminating a specific column
I have to create a function named createSubMatrix.This function receives matrix M and an integer k, and returns the submatrix obtained from M by eliminating all columns containing index k. The matrix M is generated randomly.
This is the full code I wrote, I noticed two problems :

after the first verification if the replaced column contains again the value of k it would not be replaced, I tried to make a second verification by decrementing the value of j after the end of the if but it didn't worked.

I don't know how to reduce the number of columns.
Some IA gave solutions using vectors but the work is to be made without additional libraries. Hope I was clear enough it's my first time asking a question here


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void randomMatrix(int **M, int rows, int columns){
int min = 15;
int max = 31;

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        M[i][j] = min+rand()%(max -min);
    }   
}
void stamp(int **M, int rows, int columns){

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        cout << M[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;


}

int** subMatrix(int** M, int rows, int columns, int k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
          for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j){
             if ( M[i][j] == k){
            for (int x = 0; x < rows; ++x) {
                   for (int y = j; y < columns - 1; ++y) {
                        M[x][y] = M[x][y + 1];
                    }
                }
                    //j--;
            } 
         }          
    }   
        
    return M;
}

int main(void){

    int rows;
    cout <<"Number of rows = ";
    cin >> rows;
    //cout << endl;
    int columns;
    cout <<"Number of columns = ";
    cin >> columns;
    cout << endl;
    int k;
    cout <<"value of k = ";
    cin >> k;
    cout << endl;

    int **M;
    M = new int*[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
        M[i] = new int[columns];

    randomMatrix(M ,rows, columns);
    stamp(M ,rows, columns);
    int **v = subMatrix(M, rows,columns, k);
        cout << "Sub Matrix :";
        cout << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
         }


    return 0;
}


Don't write code like this. Use std::vector.

Don't define your matrix as int **M (the use of raw naked owning pointers in C++ is not recommended). Whenever you see something like new int[n] use a std::vector Make a matrix class, and use for example a std::vector<int> to manage your memory (and do the index calculations yourself). Then add an operation that can return a new Matrix class instance without the column you want to remove.  You also tagged "C" as language, which is NOT the same language as "C++" so I removed that too.

So all in all I think you've not been taught how to use C++ properly. Have a look at learncpp.com or a good C++ book first. Specially the part about classes and memory management

Thanks for your answer and your advice I'm still new in C++ I started 1month ago just learning the basis in class and a complete course will certainly help me.

Can you show your teacher these links? Stop teaching "C", and the C++ core guidelines, I think it is time for him (her?) to update the lessons ;)

tbh, I would use a one-dimensional array instead of an array of arrays for a matrix.

Here is a solution closer to what you created (using c style arrays):
Following comments for Pepijn Kramer I am updating to a solution without C-style arrays.
matrix.h
class Matrix {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_Values;
    int m_Rows = 0;
    int m_Cols = 0;

public:
    Matrix(int rows, int cols);
    Matrix(const Matrix& other);

    void initializeRandom();
    std::vector<int> findColumnsWithKey(int key);
    Matrix getSubmatrix(const std::vector<int>& cols);
    void setValue(int row, int col, int value);

    void print();
};

matrix.cpp
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols): m_Rows(rows), m_Cols(cols)
{
    std::vector<int> row = std::vector<int>(m_Cols, 0);
    m_Values = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(m_Rows, row);
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& other)
{
    m_Rows = other.m_Rows;
    m_Cols = other.m_Cols;

    std::vector<int> row = std::vector<int>(m_Cols, 0);
    m_Values = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(m_Rows, row);

    for(int i = 0; i < m_Rows; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < m_Cols; j++){
             m_Values[i][j] = other.m_Values[i][j];
         }
    }

 }

 void Matrix::initializeRandom()
 {
     int min = 15;
     int max = 31;

     for(int i = 0; i < m_Rows; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < m_Cols; j++){
               m_Values[i][j] = min+rand()%(max -min);
          }
     }
 }

 std::vector<int> Matrix::findColumnsWithKey(int key) {
       std::vector<int> retVal;
       std::set<int> interm;
       for(int i = 0; i < m_Rows; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < m_Cols; j++){
               if (m_Values[i][j] == key)
                   interm.insert(j);
           }
       }
       for (int in : interm)
           retVal.push_back(in);
       std::sort(retVal.begin(), retVal.end());
       return retVal;
  }

  Matrix Matrix::getSubmatrix(const std::vector<int>& cols) {
       int rows = m_Rows;
       int ncols = m_Cols - cols.size();

       Matrix retVal(rows, ncols);

       for(int i = 0; i < m_Rows; i++){
            int count = 0;
            int colsidx = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < m_Cols; j++){
                 if (colsidx >= cols.size()) {
                       retVal.setValue(i, count, m_Values[i][j]);
                       count++;
                 } else {
                      if (j != cols[colsidx]) {
                          retVal.setValue(i, count, m_Values[i][j]);
                          //std::cout << "setvalue " << i << " " << count << " " << m_Values[i][j];
                          count++;
                      }
                      else
                          colsidx++;
                 }
         }
     }

     //retVal.print();
     return retVal;
 }

 void Matrix::setValue(int row, int col, int value) {
       if (row < 0 || row >= m_Rows || col < 0 || col >= m_Cols)
            return;

       m_Values[row][col] = value;
 }

 void Matrix::print()
 {
       for(int i = 0; i < m_Rows; i++){
           printf("\n");
           for(int j = 0; j < m_Cols; j++){
                printf("%d ", m_Values[i][j]);
           }
       }
 }

main.cpp
 int main() {
       Matrix m(10, 10);
       m.initializeRandom();
       printf("Initial matrix: \n");
       m.print();
       printf("\n");

       printf("Submatrix: \n");
       std::vector<int> cols = m.findColumnsWithKey(20);
       //std::sort(cols.begin(),cols.end());
       for (int c: cols)
           printf("%d ", c);
       printf("\n");
       Matrix sm = m.getSubmatrix(cols);
       printf("\n");
       return 0;
 }

In this solution at first the columns with the given key are found with the member function findColumnsWithKey and then these columns are removed from the initial matrix with the member function getSubmatrix.

no offence but I really think it is time for you to watch this video Stop teaching C and read the C++ core guidelines. Using new/delete in current C++ is not recommended

Yes. I am aware of that. I have just created a solution matching the programming style of the question. Possibly that is what the OP learned.

The algorithm for deletion is în this case în my opinion more important than how the data în the Matrix is created. Also thanks for the guidelines link. I find it very usefull.

I can imagine the algorithm for you is more important (in this case create a new matrix leaving out the row from the original matrix). However this is also a forum about C++ itself, so the answer might still be useful for other readers. Anyway good luck with your coding adventures :)

Following your comments I removed the use of C-style arrays from my implementation.

Nice, know that using std::vector<std::vector> may have one unintended side effect. The data (rows) will not be contiguous in memory which might be bad for performance (cache coherency/vectorizion). std::array<std::array<int,n>,n> will allocate one block of contiguous memory so that's why I used that. You can use std::vector but then allocate only one and do the offset calculations yourself

I am getting smarter and smarter with you. Thank you for the feedback.

You're welcome, C++ has a lot of details that can trip you up  ;)

I would expect some C++ like this where you use classes to model concepts (like a matrix) and where you will not have to call new/delete explicitly and make full use of the containers the standard library already provides:
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns) :
        m_rows{ rows },
        m_columns{ columns },
        m_values(m_rows* m_columns, 0)
    {
    }

    // Constructor from 2d array of any size
    template<std::size_t rows_v, std::size_t columns_v>
    Matrix(const int(&values)[rows_v][columns_v]) :
        Matrix{rows_v,columns_v}
    {
        for (std::size_t row{ 0ul }; row < rows_v; ++row)
        {
            for (std::size_t column{ 0ul }; column < columns_v; ++column)
            {
                at(row, column) = values[row][column];
            }
        }
    }

    void Randomize()
    {
        // Use C++'s random generation 
        static std::random_device rd{};
        static std::mt19937 generator{ rd() };
        static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random{ 15,31 };

        for (auto& value : m_values)
        {
            value = random(generator);
        }
    }

    int& at(std::size_t row, std::size_t column)
    {
        return m_values.at(index(row, column));
    }

    const int& at(std::size_t row, std::size_t column) const
    {
        return m_values.at(index(row, column));
    }

    std::size_t number_of_rows() const noexcept
    {
        return m_rows;
    }

    std::size_t number_of_columns() const noexcept
    {
        return m_columns;
    }

    // Not optimized, but will show you the idea of making
    // a function to return a matrix with a dropped column
    Matrix DropColumn(std::size_t drop_column)
    {
        Matrix new_matrix{ m_rows, m_columns - 1ul };
        for (std::size_t row{ 0ul }; row < m_rows; ++row)
        {
            for (std::size_t column{ 0ul }, new_column{ 0ul }; column < m_columns; ++column, ++new_column)
            {
                if (column == drop_column) ++column;
                new_matrix.at(row, new_column) = at(row, column);
            }
        }

        return new_matrix;
    }


private:
    std::size_t index(std::size_t row, std::size_t column) const noexcept
    {
        return (row * m_columns) + column;
    }

    std::size_t m_rows;
    std::size_t m_columns;
    std::vector<int> m_values;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix& matrix)
{
    for (std::size_t row{ 0ul }; row < matrix.number_of_rows(); ++row)
    {
        os << "[";
        bool comma = false;
        for (std::size_t column{ 0ul }; column < matrix.number_of_columns(); ++column)
        {
            if (comma) os << ",";
            comma = true;
            os << matrix.at(row, column);
        }
        os << "]\n";
    }

    return os;
}


int main()
{
    Matrix m1{ {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}} };
    assert(m1.at(1, 1) == 2);
    std::cout << "m1 :\n";
    std::cout << m1;

    Matrix m2{ m1.DropColumn(1) };
    assert(m2.number_of_columns() == 2ul);
    std::cout << "m2 :\n";
    std::cout << m2;

    Matrix m3{ 3,3 };
    m3.Randomize();
    std::cout << "m3 :\n";
    std::cout << m3;
}


I'm afraid there's also some confusion in OP's question about the term "index" (please note the if ( M[i][j] == k) line in their code and the first point in the question).
